# Create an array from data received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, screen-scraping, models

I am trying to learn how to get data via a screen scrape and then save it to a model. So far I can grab the data. I say this as if I do:

```
puts home_team
```

I get all the home teams returned

get_match.rb #grabbing the data

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

module MatchGrabber::GetMatch

FIXTURE_URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/fixtures"

def get_fixtures
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
home_team =  doc.css(".team-home.teams").text
end
end
```

Then i want to update my model

match_fixtures.rb

```
 module MatchFixtures
 class MatchFixtures
 include MatchGrabber::GetMatch

def perform
  update_fixtures
end

private

 def update_fixtures
  Fixture.destroy_all
  fixtures = get_fixtures
end

def update_db(matches)
  matches.each do |match|
    fixture = Fixture.new(
      home_team: match.first
      )
    fixture.save
 end
end
end
end
```

So the next step is where I am getting stuck. First of all I need to put the home_team results into an array?

Second part is I am passing matches through my update_db method but that's not correct, what do I pass through here, the results of the home_team from my update_fixtures method or the method itself?

To run the task I do:

```
namespace :grab do
task :fixtures => :environment do
MatchFixtures::MatchFixtures.new.perform
end
end
```

But nothing is saved, but that is to be expected.

Steep learning curve here and would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `css(".team-home.teams").text` does not return the matching DOM elements as an array, but as a single string.

In order to obtain an array of elements, refactor get fixture into something like this:

```
get_teams
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(FIXTURE_URL))
  doc.css(".team-home.teams").map { |el| el.text.strip }
end
```

This will return an array containing the text of the elements matching your selector, stripped out of blank and new line characters. At this point you can loop over the returned array and pass each team as an argument to your model's `create` method:

```
get_teams.each { |team| Fixture.create(home_team: team) }
```

Comment: thanks that has cleared some more up for me, though it seems to be stripping the first letter only for each home team, it now posts to db which is great but now need to get the whole  word rather than just first letter

Comment: ok so i used .split(' ') instead of strip, only problem now is that when there is a team called West Ham for example I only get West

Comment: String#strip "returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed". 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip

Comment: thanks, realised a mistake my end, was putting .first on the end of team when saving to model

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the array directly to the update method:

```
def update_fixtures
  Fixture.destroy_all
  update_db(get_fixtures)
end

def update_db(matches)
  matches.each {|match| Fixture.create(home_team: match.first) }
end
```

Or do away with the method all together:

```
def update_fixtures
  Fixture.destroy_all
  get_fixtures.each {|match| Fixture.create(home_team: match.first) }
end
```

Comment: now i get undefined method .each, would that be because my columnn in model is set to string and im pulling down data as text. the results are not coming down as an array? Thank you for your help

Comment: That's because I thought get_fixtures was returning an array.  What does it return?

Comment: sorry that was part of my question, how to convert the results of home_team into an array. If i do a puts i get this for example Chelsea Man utd Liverpool Bolton, in a vertical list, no commas seperating them just one under each other. sorry if thats not helpful

Comment: Not an array?  try: `get_fixtures.collect {|match| Fixture.create(home_team: match.first) }`.  It's hard to visualize what you're seeing.